# counting uniq values in array not working

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary, count

this is my code to count uniq values in perl array and put them in hash array

```
@array=$_[0];

print Dumper @array;

my %counts;

$counts{$_}++ for @array;
print Dumper(\%counts);
```

The output is :

```
$VAR1 = [
          -46,
          '53',
          11,
          '84',
          -2,
          '47',
          -7,
          '72',
          0,
          '14',
          -10,
          '3',
          -46,
          '53',
          11,
          '84',
          -2,
          '47',
          -7,
          '72',
          0,
          '14',
          -10,
          '3'
        ];
$VAR1 = {
          'ARRAY(0x180c844)' => 1
        };
```

Why the hash array is empty ?? And what to do in order to count the uniq values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an array ref in `$_[0]`, which is demonstrated by the `Data::Dumper` output

```
$VAR1 = [ ....
#       ^-- array ref
```

So when you do

```
$counts{$_}++ for @array;
```

You are stringifying the array ref, which becomes `ARRAY(0x180c844)` or some such, and then its key is incremented.

How to fix: Dereference `$_[0]`. Copy it to the array or use it directly.

```
@array = @{$_[0]};
```

or

```
$counts{$_}++ for @{$_[0]};
```

You should note that when checking for unique numbers, you may run into problems if numbers that look differently should be considered the same, e.g. `1.0` and `1`. You may want to normalize the numbers beforehand, like so:

```
$counds{ 0+$_ }++ for @array;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just copying the array into an array reference.. perl is interpreted contextually.

Try:

```
@array=@{$_[0]};

print Dumper @array;

my %counts;

map { $counts{$_}++ } @array;
print Dumper(\%counts);
```

Edit: I used my own input at first and not the array-ref in the initial variable.. the dereference proposed should fix it.

Comment: I just ran it in perl shell and got the expected output a hashref with the keys as the value and the value as the number of times occurred

Comment: Didn't notice the array reference, which is why it worked in psh for me.. just used a qw() of a few values.. updated my answer